# how to find total count of two matching files

Tags: bash

I have two text files Like

```
file1 
1018 2 
1019 7
1023 4

file2
1018 2 
1019 7
1023 4
1026 8
```

I have a small bash code to find match and count

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=1; next} $0 in a { count[$0]++ } 
  END { for( i in a ) print i, count[i]}' file1 file2
```

the output I get;

```
1018 2  1
1019 7  1
1023 4  1
```

`I just want total count that is in this case: 3.` Its simple to print count after the loop but didn't work, any solution....

Comment: `END{print length(a)}`? Or just `count++` and then `END{print count}`

Comment: Please add expected output to your question.

Comment: it count the number of lines in file1 even if it did not match with the file two.... I want when it matches than it count and at the end get number matches.....

Comment: `comm -12 file1 file2 | wc -l`. Assuming they're sorted.

Answer (score 0):

When I have an outputted list in bash I'll use "wc". WC does a word count and you can specify it to count the number of lines. So say I want to count the number of files in a directory. I'll do:

```
ls -lh | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `sort` and `uniq` to do so. This is how it would look like:

```
cat file1 file2 | sort | uniq -d | wc -l
```

Explanation:

- `cat` is used to concatenate the two files
- `sort` is used to sort the merged content
- `uniq` (with option `-d`) is used to only show duplicated lines
- `wc` (with option `-l`) is counting the left lines